# JAXB + JDO marshalling produces empty XML root element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, jdo

This is my problem: I have achieved the unmarshalling of an XML and the storage of the objects in RDBMS successfully. I can retrieve the objects from the database well.
However, I can't seem to get the marshalling part to work properly.

This is my code for marshalling:

```
//JAXB MARSHALLING
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try
    {
        tx.begin();
        Extent e = pm.getExtent(DELVRY03Type.class,true);
        Iterator iter = e.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            DELVRY03Type delvry03 = (DELVRY03Type)iter.next();

            ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
            JAXBElement<DELVRY03Type> je = objectFactory.createDELVRY03(delvry03);

            marshaller.marshal(je, System.out);
        }
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("READ"); 
    }
    finally
    {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        pm.close();
    }
```

DELVRY03Type is my main class (the xml root element).
The strange thing is that if I get the inner objects (childs) of *delvry03* once retrieved from the database, I can read their attributes just fine. But this is what it shows in the output from the marshalling to XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <DELVRY03/> READ
```

What could be the problem? How can it be that the objects are fine and then the marshalling produces an empty root element?

I have tried to do a concatenated unmarshalling + marshalling without storing the objects in a database and it does a perfect marshalling, I am confused.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: class contains something that JAXB can't cope with ? fields of object are loaded before trying to marshall? Tried just persisting with DataNucleus JDO to XML direct (which uses JAXB behind the scenes)?

Comment: @NeilStockton I think JAXB must cope with what is inside the classes because is precisely JAXB who has generated them, and I haven't touched them in any way. The object is retrieved from database before marhsalling (with an Extent) and if I use the methods "getXXX" they give me the subclasses with their attributes just fine. The problem is that JAXB seems not to find anything in the JAXBElement. I didn't know there was a JDO to XML mechanism, how could I use it? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You could easily enough get objects from your RDBMS, detach them, and then have a PMF for the XML datastore, and attach the objects to that to write the XML file.